# Trying to create custom regular expression for a file name in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have multiple file names that I need to parse. One commonality between these files is that level (revision) is the last letter before the dot. I need to have a regular expression that that accepts the hyphen (-), also.

Examples of file names:

1. 068394B.dwg
2. 06841213E.dwg
3. 420676-.dwg

Comment: what do you want to match

Comment: You may get an answer anyway, but question would be much better if you show your effort to find answer yourself.

Comment: Why not just split at the last period and get the last letter of the file name? 'Accepts' any (supported) char.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ <-- Following on what Alexei said, this is a good site to learn a bit about regex so you can take an initial stab at it yourself and then come back with specific questions when/if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
@"^\d*[a-zA-Z\-]\.dwg$"
```

The syntax should be the same for c# too

---

If you need to capture groups, you can use parenthesies to do that.

so for instance:

```
@"^(\d*)([a-zA-Z\-])\.dwg$"
```

will capture your number and your code at the end.

you `Match` should have a collection called `Groups` the first one will be the full match, where the subsequent ones will be the groups in the parens.

---

more details at [This reference page](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

[Here's a sample](http://rubular.com/r/i8MiTHl9Sc)

Comment: This sample would probably be a tiny bit clearer: http://regex101.com/r/uB4lU7 -- +1 for good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't really need a regular expression for that. You can use the `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and `Path.GetExtension` to get the name and extension parts. Then use `name.Substring(0, name.Length - 1)` and `name[name.Length-1]` to get the number and revison.

Use `Int32.TryParse` to check if the number is a number, and `if ((ext >= 'A' && ext <= 'Z') || ext == '-')` to check that the revision is valid.

Comment: Need to parse file name that ends with a zero (0) or a letter (A-Z) that is used for revision. For example: file name 40088803B.dwg need to be parsed and letter B to captured.

Comment: Use `string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName); char rev = name[name.Length-1];`to get the revision.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a list of filenames in `lstFn`

You can do

```
List<string> lstPFn=lstFn.Where(f=>Regex.IsMatch(f,@"^.*\.d.*$"))
                         .ToList<string>();
```